# maven compilation error: duplicate classes

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

In my maven2 project I have a directory `${basedir}/autogen` that contains some autogenerated source code files produced by `wsdl2java`.

When running `mvn compile` I get an compilation error, because of duplicate classes, that lives in `${basedir}/autogen`. This is true. But what is the compilation phase doing in `${basedir}/autogen`?  I have not told maven to add this directory as a source directory.
 And there seems to be no way of telling maven to ignore the directory.

Comment: @vpalle can you list the duplicated class names? are they dupes of javax.* classes?

Comment: I am having a similar issue I need to digest a wsdl web service and a schema xsd. Neither has all I need, but in the overlap there are dups which then throw duplicat class errors on compile.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem when using the maven-processor-plugin and found that the solution was to configure the maven-compiler plugin as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

-proc:none means that compilation takes place without annotation processing and therefore no duplicate classes (which are typically generated in the generate-sources phase)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hibernate's JPA Static Metamodel Generator documentation states that you can use the solution provided above in combination with the maven-processor-plugin if you want to control the execution of the processor

Comment: It didn't help, my JAR archive still contains duplicate class files.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this a few times. In almost all cases, it is due to the generated classes being added to the main src tree then checked into version control.

Comment: They weren't added to version control in the first place, just checked, so I guess thats not the issue..

Comment: This anwser is very, very useful. Thank you sir. Double check if your local configuration changes didn't produce classes in main folder. Then doesn't (and probably won't) be put into the version control because nobody ever wants to commit not working code.

Comment: That was my problem! Thanks

Comment: This was my problem indeed

Comment: This answers will be way better if it provided a solution.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it worked when I changed source directory.

New POM looks like,

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

Pointing just a src folder with sourceDirectory tag.

Earlier it was

```
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
```

Note that earlier it was working in IntellIJ, but not on cmd.
Now it works on both.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with JPA model generator. It occurred on this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I wrongly added the scope=provided and that resulted in:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project mocker: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Projects\entity\MockVehicle_.java:[10,7] duplicate class: entity.MockVehicle_
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. In my case the problem was that I called maven with `-f=./pom.xml`. I have no idea why this leads to a different result (would be nice if someone can explain) but maybe good to know if someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it by remove generateAsync from my pom.xml the the GWT plugin will look like

```
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <!-- <goal>i18n</goal> -->

                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

Comment: Line removed is below 
<goal>generateAsync</goal>

Comment: this worked for me (Maven, GWT, requestfactory build)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to change default maven behaviour, i think its better to go with it - you could generate those files with maven [wsdl2java-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wsdl2java-maven-plugin/howto.html)

Comment: I am generating them with a maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I my case helped this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers here where not helpful. This may be the correct answer:

Another StackOverflow user wrote:

> I have found an JetBrains Team member comment stating that:
>
> > IDEA automatically excludes the build 'target' folder, providing that
> >     there are no generated sources under it, otherwise it excludes all
> >     sub-folders but the generated.

Avro by standard in a `generated-sources` folder. This folder it not ignored by maven ans the generated classes in there will count as duplicate. 
Maven will only igonre the `target` folder by default.

To fix add this line in the `pom.xml`:

```
 <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/target/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
```

Context:

```
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/target/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <createSetters>false</createSetters>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/</outputDirectory><enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

This will put the `generated-resources` folder under the `target` folder.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve the same issue

> 1. cleaning maven project :-`mvn clean`
> 2. delete com folder from src then compile
> 3. copy com from generated to src->main-->java
> 4. again compile

Hope this Help..