# Maven duplicates all my .class files in the JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

I've been having running optimizers on my JAR. I've always wondered why. Today I wanted to replace single `.class` file, and when I opened the jar, I looked at this in the `/cz/autoclient/` directory:

[image: image description]

No wonder archivers couldn't handle that mess. I found [some advice on `maven-compiler-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7467971/607407) configuration, that didn't help. This is my build configuration in the `pom.xml`:

```
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${test.dir}</testSourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${resource.dir}</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>cz.autoclient.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>src/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>cz.autoclient.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
```

I really need to resolve it. Apart of the JAR optimizers, it also breaks java official tools:

```
jar uf AutoClient.jar version
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: cz/autoclient/autoclick/ColorPixel.class
        at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:233)
        at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.update(Main.java:630)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:269)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1233)
```

What causes the duplicate class files and how to resolve this issue? Only files in `/cz/autoclient/` - that's the compiled source - seem to be duplicated.

Comment: Please post your complete pom, or the complete log of the maven run. What is the value of ${src.dir}, ${test.dir} and ${resource.dir}? They might be overlapping. You may have something duplication on the things that are used by the assembly plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should remove that:

```xml
 <testSourceDirectory>${test.dir}</testSourceDirectory>
 <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
 <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${resource.dir}</directory>
    </resource>
 </resources>
```

Except you know 100% what you are doing but based on your post you don't. So remove it..

Furthermore use an more uptodate version of maven-assembly-plugin and not such ancient version... See here:  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Copying version numbers for my plugins from that exact link fixed the problem without any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

A check for anonymous classes (in my case via IntelliJ) may show stuff like (in my case) map creation on the fly

```
myMethod(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
    put("1", "2");
    put("3", "4");
    put("5", "6");
}});
```

12 occurrences in my class, 12 additional classfiles in warfile.